# Is there any order when searching names in namespaces?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Hope that I am not asking a dumb question. I did search it in Google but couldn't find much information.

I have the following simple code quoted from Exceptional C++ Book Item 31 by Herb Sutter:

```
namespace NS
{
    class T{};
    void f(T);
}

void f(NS::T);
int main()
{
    NS::T params;
    f(params);
}
```

When I compiled it:

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   prog.cpp:12:13: error: call of overloaded ‘f(NS::T&)’ is ambiguous
>   prog.cpp:12:13: note: candidates are:
>   prog.cpp:8:6: note: void f(NS::T)
>   prog.cpp:4:10: note: void NS::f(NS::T)

I understand that it is because of argument dependent lookup for `f`. The compiler found two version of `f`, one in global namespace, one in `NS` namespace.

My question are:

1. **Is there any order when searching for a name in multiple namespaces?**
2. **Should it be always searching for enclosing namespace first then to global namespaces?**
3. **If this is the case, why there is still ambiguity if we already found a match in `NS` namespace?**

Please feel free to correct me if my questions are not clear.

Thank you.

Comment: Somewhat relevant - the order would only be relevant if searching would stop at the first match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3.4.2.3 [basic.lookup.argdep] seems to imply that ADL will be performed after the usual unqualified name lookup procedure.

The section on unqualified name lookup indicates that name resolution starts at the narrowest scope and moves outward.

```
[ Example:
class B { };
namespace M {
   namespace N {
      class X : public B {
         void f();
      };
   }
}
void M::N::X::f() {
   i = 16;
}
// The following scopes are searched for a declaration of i:
// 1) outermost block scope of M::N::X::f, before the use of i
// 2) scope of class M::N::X
// 3) scope of M::N::X’s base class B
// 4) scope of namespace M::N
// 5) scope of namespace M
// 6) global scope, before the definition of M::N::X::f
—end example ]
```

Comment: Thank you for referring to C++ standard such that I can read more about it.